# Error in fetching data using axios library

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am having a trouble making an http request in my application.

https://excuser-three.vercel.app/v1/excuse/party/

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

export const Mohamed=()=> {

  const[user,setUser]=useState("")

  const Mudi=(excuse)=>{

    axios.get(`https://excuser-three.vercel.app/v1/excuse/${excuse}/`).then(res=>{
      setUser(res.data[0].excuse)
      console.log(res.data[0].excuse)
    })
  } 

  useEffect(()=>{ Mudi() },[])

  return(
      <div>
          <button onClick={()=>Mudi("party") }>Party</button>
          {user}
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What sort of trouble?

Comment: i failed to fetch a message i don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You actually have no problem with your data-fetching, but a faulty Effect in your component. You are calling `Mudi()` the first time you load the component without any parameters. `Mudi()` however has a non-optional parameter `excuse`, that is not set and therefore you are trying to fetch: https://excuser-three.vercel.app/v1/excuse/undefined/

You have three ways to fix this:

1. Remove the complete useEffect:

   `useEffect(() => { Mudi() }, [])`
2. Change the useEffect to a proper function call:

   `useEffect(() => { Mudi("party") }, [])`
3. Change the Mudi function and make the parameter optional:

   `const Mudi = (excuse = "party") => {`

Another option would be to change your API, so that calling "undefined" also returns a proper value.